# Display data on my codeigniter view page from the same database table but with different categories (using the same model and controller)

Tags: codeigniter, categories

All of this has worked fine for a year, however now I have to separate my goals on the same page between 2020 and 2021. I have "goal_year" as my column within the "goals_table" database table.

I tried to create 2 separate cells where the code pulls in goals for 2020 and goals for 2021 but it makes the entire page show blank.

**I'm trying to do this without creating a separate model and controller file.**

**DATABASE**

```
id | district  |  goal_year | goal_af_am_msm | goal_b | goal_c
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |   macon   |    2020    |      456       |   87   |  234
 2 |   cobb    |    2020    |      987       |   34   |  762
 3 |   macon   |    2021    |      432       |   67   |  819
 4 |   fulton  |    2021    |      843       |   21   |  236
```

Here's my code:

**MODEL**

```
  function _goal()
  {
    $this->db->where('district', 'macon');
        $query = $this->db->get('goals_table');
        return $query->row();
    
  }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public function index()
    {        
        $data['_goal_data'] = $this->Macon_model->_goal(); // GOALS

        $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'macon', $data);

    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<td>
 <?php echo $_goal_data->goal_af_am_msm; ?> <!-- ENTERED GOALS -->
</td>
```

**ALTERNATE VIEWS THAT I TRIED**

```
1).
<td>
 <?php echo $_goal_data->goal_af_am_msm->where('goal_year','2020'); ?> 
<!-- Shows entire page blank -->
</td>


2).
<td>
 <?php if($_goal_data->goal_year == '2020') echo $_goal_data->goal_af_am_msm ; ?> 
<!-- Shows 2020 GOALS but show blank for 2021 -->
</td>


3).
<td>
 <?php echo $_goal_data->goal_year == '2020' ? $_goal_data->goal_af_am_msm : ''; ?> 
<!-- Shows 2020 GOALS but show blank for 2021 -->
</td>
```

Comment: Can you post the DB schema for that table please

Comment: Database schema added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kept playing around with it and I got it figured out. I ended up having to change my model from

```
return $query->row();
```

to

```
return $query->result();
```

Then I had to update my view file to

```
<?php foreach($_goal_data as $macon_data) : ?>
<?php if($macon_data->goal_year == '2020') echo $macon_data->goal_af_am_msm; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```